# delphi indy10 udp client/server send stream (memory usage)

Tags: delphi, sockets, tcp, udp, indy10

i did an image streaming using idudpclient and server and all worked well, but for each image sent, i saw from task manager that the memory usage is higher and after a minute i had this error "not enough storage is available to process this command". I tried to free all stream created at runtime but without succes. This is a sample code:

```
procedure TForm5.mandaimg;
  var
  bmp,bmp1,bmp2,bmp3,bmp4: TBitmap;
  jpg1,jpg2,jpg3,jpg4: TJPEGImage;
  Strm1,Strm2,Strm3,Strm4 : TMemoryStream;
  cStrm1,cStrm2,cStrm3,cStrm4 : TMemoryStream;  //stream compressi

  strmByte1,strmByte2,strmByte3,strmByte4:TIdBytes;
begin
   strmByte1:=nil;
    strmByte2:=nil;
    strmByte3:=nil;
    strmByte4:=nil;
 if(IdUDPClient1.Connected = false)then
 begin
   IdUDPClient1.connect;
   IdUDPClient2.connect;
   IdUDPClient3.connect;
   IdUDPClient4.connect;
 end;
 if(IdUDPClient1.Connected)then
 begin
  Strm1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Strm1.Position := 0;
  Strm2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Strm2.Position := 0;
  Strm3 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Strm3.Position := 0;
  Strm4 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Strm4.Position := 0;       

  cStrm1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  cStrm1.Position := 0;
  cStrm2 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  cStrm2.Position := 0;
  cStrm3 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  cStrm3.Position := 0;
  cStrm4 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  cStrm4.Position := 0;
  try
    jpg1 := TJPEGImage.Create;
    jpg2 := TJPEGImage.Create;
    jpg3 := TJPEGImage.Create;
    jpg4 := TJPEGImage.Create;
    bmp1 := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp2 := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp3 := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp4 := TBitmap.Create;
    try
      bmp := TBitmap.Create;
      try
        screenshot(bmp);
        img1.Picture.Assign(bmp);
      CropBitmap(img1.Picture.Bitmap, Bmp1, 0,0, Round(Screen.width/2), Round(Screen.Height/2));
  //    Image1.Picture.Bitmap:=Bmp1;
      CropBitmap(img1.Picture.Bitmap, Bmp2, Round(Screen.width/2),0, Round(Screen.width/2), Round(Screen.Height/2));
   //   Image2.Picture.Bitmap:=Bmp2;
      CropBitmap(img1.Picture.Bitmap, Bmp3, 0,Round(Screen.Height/2), Round(screen.width/2), Round(Screen.Height/2));
   //   Image3.Picture.Bitmap:=Bmp3;
      CropBitmap(img1.Picture.Bitmap, Bmp4, Round(Screen.width/2),Round(Screen.Height/2), Round(Screen.width/2), Round(Screen.Height/2));
   //   Image4.Picture.Bitmap:=Bmp4;

      jpg1.Assign(bmp1);
      jpg1.CompressionQuality:=TrackBar1.Position;
      jpg1.Compress;
      jpg2.Assign(bmp2);
      jpg2.CompressionQuality:=TrackBar1.Position;
      jpg2.Compress;
      jpg3.Assign(bmp3);
      jpg3.CompressionQuality:=TrackBar1.Position;
      jpg3.Compress;
      jpg4.Assign(bmp4);
      jpg4.CompressionQuality:=TrackBar1.Position;
      jpg4.Compress;
      finally
          jpg1.SaveToStream(Strm1);
          jpg2.SaveToStream(Strm2);
          jpg3.SaveToStream(Strm3);
          jpg4.SaveToStream(Strm4);
          Strm1.Position:=0;
          Strm2.Position:=0;
          Strm3.Position:=0;
          Strm4.Position:=0;
          CompressStream(Strm1,cStrm1);
          CompressStream(Strm2,cStrm2);
          CompressStream(Strm3,cStrm3);
          CompressStream(Strm4,cStrm4);

      end;
    finally
      jpg1.Free;
      jpg2.Free;
      jpg3.Free;
      jpg4.Free;
      bmp1.Free;
      bmp2.Free;
      bmp3.Free;
      bmp4.Free;
    end;
      cStrm1.Position := 0;
      cStrm2.Position := 0;
      cStrm3.Position := 0;
      cStrm4.Position := 0;
 try
    ReadTIdBytesFromStream(cStrm1,strmByte1,cStrm1.Size);
    IdUDPClient1.SendBuffer('192.168.17.132',1235,strmByte1);

    ReadTIdBytesFromStream(cStrm2,strmByte2,cStrm2.Size);
    IdUDPClient2.SendBuffer('192.168.17.132',1236,strmByte2);

    ReadTIdBytesFromStream(cStrm3,strmByte3,cStrm3.Size);
    IdUDPClient3.SendBuffer('192.168.17.132',1237,strmByte3);

    ReadTIdBytesFromStream(cStrm4,strmByte4,cStrm4.Size);
    IdUDPClient4.SendBuffer('192.168.17.132',1238,strmByte4);
 except
      TrackBar1.Position:=TrackBar1.Position-1;
 end;
  finally

FreeAndNil(strm1);
FreeAndNil(strm2);
FreeAndNil(strm3);
FreeAndNil(strm4);
 FreeAndNil(cstrm1);
FreeAndNil(cstrm2);
FreeAndNil(cstrm3);
FreeAndNil(cstrm4);
    strmByte1:=nil;
    strmByte2:=nil;
    strmByte3:=nil;
    strmByte4:=nil;
  end;
end;

end;
```

Can i do something?

Thanks in advance.

(I'm using delphi xe5)

Comment: How's it look if you free `cStrm5`? I'm not sure what you're doing with `bmp` since you're creating it here. I hope you free it if you're calling this code more than once.

Comment: cstrm5 is a test, i updated the example, the proble persist without cstrm5

Comment: Did you enable memory leak reporting via the RTL's `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown` global variable in the `System` unit? That will give you basic information about any memory your code is leaking. For more detailed information, you can install the full version of [FastMM](http://fastmm.sourceforge.net) and enable its FullDebugMode option.

Comment: i had this error: http://oi43.tinypic.com/k153d.jpg  what i can do?

Comment: Problem solved! with bmp.free;